# How to refer to a column of a data.table by its position, in a sum() statement

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I've googled the issue as many ways as my brain is capable of and I still can't find the answer. I'm new to R so there are some things that confuse me a little bit.

Let's say I have a data table like this:

```
   x y z 100 200 300
1: 1 1 a   1   1   1
2: 1 1 b   2   3   4
3: 1 2 c   3   5   7
4: 1 2 d   4   7   0
5: 2 1 e   5   9   3
6: 2 1 f   6   1   6
7: 2 2 g   7   3   9
8: 2 2 h   8   5   2
```

This can be created with this piece of code:

```
DT = setDT(structure(list(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                         c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                         c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),
                         c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                         c(1,3,5,7,9,1,3,5),
                         c(1,4,7,0,3,6,9,2)),
                    .Names = c("x", "y", "z", 100, 200, 300), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame"))
```

However, in my actual code, the last three columns were auto-generated using another function (`dcast`), so the total number of columns of the `data.table` is not static. Also, you may notice that the names of those three last columns are numeric, which might be a problem at some point.

What I need is to create one aditional column for each "extra" column (the ones right after column "z"). I need the code to work such as this example: first, it creates column "100s", then for each row, it calculates the sum of column "100", considering only the rows with the same combination of `x`,`y` that the row in question. And so on for "200s" and "300s". Like this:

```
   x y z 100 200 300 100s 200s 300s
1: 1 1 a   1   1   1    3    4    5
2: 1 1 b   2   3   4    3    4    5
3: 1 2 c   3   5   7    7   12    7
4: 1 2 d   4   7   0    7   12    7
5: 2 1 e   5   9   3   11   10    9
6: 2 1 f   6   1   6   11   10    9
7: 2 2 g   7   3   9   15    8   11
8: 2 2 h   8   5   2   15    8   11
```

I've tried with several modifications of this idea of a code:

```
for (i in 3:(dim(DT)[2])) {
  DT <- DT[,paste(colnames(DT)[i], "s", sep=""):=sum(i),
                   by=c("x","y")]
}
```

This gives me the following result:

```
   x y z 100 200 300 100s 200s 300s
1: 1 1 a   1   1   1    4    5    6
2: 1 1 b   2   3   4    4    5    6
3: 1 2 c   3   5   7    4    5    6
4: 1 2 d   4   7   0    4    5    6
5: 2 1 e   5   9   3    4    5    6
6: 2 1 f   6   1   6    4    5    6
7: 2 2 g   7   3   9    4    5    6
8: 2 2 h   8   5   2    4    5    6
```

Of course, R is not recognizing the numeric value of i as the number of column it should consider for the sum, as instead it's taking it as a raw number. I can't figure out how to adress a specific column by its position, because when it comes to sum(), that "with=FALSE" thing fails to save the day.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ZahiroMor What you are saying is wrong. Did you actually try to do `DT[,4]` on a `data.table`? You are right in the `data.frame` case, but OP has a `data.table`. In this case, to select a column by number you have to use `.SDcols`, for instance `DT[,.SD,.SDcols=1:3]` selects the first 3 columns.

Comment: Fwiw, what Zahiro describes with `DT[, 4]` is planned behavior for data.table.

Comment: @nicola you are correct. I generally use data.frames and misread.

Comment: @nicola  `DT[,1:3,with=FALSE]` also selects the first 3 columns but we're going to change it so that `DT[,1:3]` works too, like `data.frame` rather than returning the value `[1 2 3]`. Will still be backwards compatible since nobody will have been using `DT[,1:3]`.  That's why we started that way around until we were sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for using a `for` loop in this case to get the desired result. You can update `DT` by reference with:

```
DT[, paste0(colnames(DT)[3:5],'s') := lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x,y)]
```

which will give you the desired result:

```
> DT
   x y 100 200 300 100s 200s 300s
1: 1 1   1   1   1    3    4    5
2: 1 1   2   3   4    3    4    5
3: 1 2   3   5   7    7   12    7
4: 1 2   4   7   0    7   12    7
5: 2 1   5   9   3   11   10    9
6: 2 1   6   1   6   11   10    9
7: 2 2   7   3   9   15    8   11
8: 2 2   8   5   2   15    8   11
```

When you don't know exacly which columns to sum, you could use one of the following methods:

```
# method 1:
DT[, paste0(colnames(DT)[3:ncol(DT)],'s') := lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x,y)]
# method 2:
DT[, paste0(setdiff(colnames(DT), c('x','y')),'s') := lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x,y)]
```

---

With the updated example, probably the best way to do is:

```
cols <- setdiff(colnames(DT), c('x','y','z'))
DT[, paste0(cols,'s') := lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x,y), .SDcols = cols]
```

which gives:

```
> DT
   x y z 100 200 300 100s 200s 300s
1: 1 1 a   1   1   1    3    4    5
2: 1 1 b   2   3   4    3    4    5
3: 1 2 c   3   5   7    7   12    7
4: 1 2 d   4   7   0    7   12    7
5: 2 1 e   5   9   3   11   10    9
6: 2 1 f   6   1   6   11   10    9
7: 2 2 g   7   3   9   15    8   11
8: 2 2 h   8   5   2   15    8   11
```

Comment: Great, but what if I have a column whose values are characters, and I want to leave that column untouched? Let's say if after "y" there's a "z" column with characters on it. It gives me the following error: Error in sum(z) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument. I'm going to edit the question so other people way answer as well.

Comment: `mycols = c("100","200","300"); DT[, paste0(mycols, "s") := lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(x,y) .SDcols = mycols]` @JAR

Comment: @Frank This works, but I don't know exactly _how many_ columns would I need to sum, or _what would their names be_. As I've said, those are auto-generated so instead of "100","200","300" I could have for example "75","1000", depending on the source data. The only thing I know is that they are the last columns after some static number of columns in the DT.

EDIT: I found it by myself. Just replace mycols by colnames(DT)[4:dim(DT)[2]]. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @JAR I've updated the answer for the case of unknown number of columns to sum. HTH

Comment: @JAR updated the answer with a method that doesn't try to sum the `z` column